The Indesign script returns the page number as a single-digit number
First of all, I would like to say that I have no idea about programming; I have simply been developing a script for InDesign using AI, and I have reached a point where I cannot continue. What I am looking for is for the script to go through the entire document to return an Excel file where the codes of the articles are located, as well as the page number where they are found. The problem is that in the resulting CSV file, the page number behaves correctly in documents with fewer than 10 pages, enumerating correctly. However, starting from page 10, it simply writes 1 for the pages from 10 to 19 and 2 for those from 20 to 29, and so on.
var now = new Date();
var hours = ("0" + now.getHours()).slice(-2); // Formato HH
var minutes = ("0" + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2); // Formato MM
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2); // Formato DD
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // Formato MM (mes)

// Crear el nombre del archivo CSV con la fecha y hora
var fileName = hours + minutes + "_" + day + month + ".csv";
var file = new File("~/Documentos/" + fileName);

try {
    file.open("w"); // Abrir el archivo en modo escritura
    file.writeln("Código,Página"); // Escribir el encabezado con la nueva columna

    // Comprobación de que hay un documento abierto
    if (app.documents.length > 0) {
        var doc = app.activeDocument;
        var totalCodigos = 0; // Variable para contar los códigos encontrados

        // Función para procesar elementos de texto
        function processTextFrames(textFrames, pageNumber) {
            for (var j = 0; j < textFrames.length; j++) {
                var textFrame = textFrames[j];

                // Recorrer todas las tablas en el marco de texto
                for (var k = 0; k < textFrame.tables.length; k++) {
                    var table = textFrame.tables[k];

                    // Acceder a la primera columna
                    var firstColumnCells = table.columns[0].cells;

                    // Recorrer cada celda en la primera columna
                    for (var l = 0; l < firstColumnCells.length; l++) {
                        var cellContent = firstColumnCells[l].contents;

                        // Buscar secuencias de 8 dígitos
                        var matches = cellContent.match(/\b\d{8}\b/g);

                        if (matches) {
                            totalCodigos += matches.length; // Contar los códigos encontrados

                            for (var m = 0; m < matches.length; m++) {
                                // Escribir el código y el número de página en columnas separadas
                                file.writeln(matches[m] + "," + pageNumber);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Buscar códigos en cajas de texto
                var textContent = textFrame.contents;
                var codigoMatches = textContent.match(/Cód:\s*(\d{8})/g);

                if (codigoMatches) {
                    totalCodigos += codigoMatches.length; // Contar los códigos encontrados

                    for (var n = 0; n < codigoMatches.length; n++) {
                        var codigo = codigoMatches[n].match(/\d{8}/)[0]; // Extraer solo el código
                        // Escribir el código y el número de página en columnas separadas
                        file.writeln(codigo + "," + pageNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Función recursiva para procesar grupos
        function processGroups(groups, pageNumber) {
            for (var g = 0; g < groups.length; g++) {
                var group = groups[g];
                processTextFrames(group.textFrames, pageNumber); // Procesar marcos de texto dentro del grupo
                processGroups(group.groups, pageNumber); // Llamar a la función recursiva para grupos anidados
            }
        }

        // Recorrer todas las páginas del documento
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.pages.length; i++) {
            var page = doc.pages[i];

            // Procesar los marcos de texto en la página
            processTextFrames(page.textFrames, page.name);

            // Procesar grupos en la página
            processGroups(page.groups, page.name); // Procesar grupos en la página
        }

        // Mensaje final de confirmación
        if (totalCodigos > 0) {
            alert("Os códigos dos artigos foron exportados correctamente a " + file.fullName + ". Total de códigos: " + totalCodigos);
        } else {
            alert("Non se atoparon códigos de 8 díxitos no documento.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Non hai documentos abertos en InDesign.");
    }
} catch (e) {
    alert("Ocurriu un erro: " + e.message);
} finally {
    file.close(); // Cerrar el archivo CSV
}



What happens if you pass i instead of page.name when first calling processGroups and processTextFrames? Side note: consider putting the functions apart from the rest of the code (i.e. at the end) it will make things easier to parse

Can you reduce this to a [mre]? All that matters is the code that uses the page number, the rest is just a distraction.

What does console.log(page.name) show?

@Barmar there is no console.log(). In Extend script we have $.writeln(). And it works only if ExtendScript ToolKit is installed. Otherwise the oldy-goldy alert() is your friend. And yes, it would be great to see what the variable page.name contains.

The code looks fine. I'd try to change the variable page.name with the counter i+1. It could be enough if your documents have the simply numeration of the pages (1, 2, 3, etc).
Instead of this:
processTextFrames(page.textFrames, page.name);
processGroups(page.groups, page.name);

You can try this:
processTextFrames(page.textFrames, i+1);
processGroups(page.groups, i+1);

Just in case, as far as I can see you probably don't even need to loop through all the text frames on every page. You can get all the matches with just one step and loop through the matches and get page numbers from every match. Something like this:
var now      = new Date();
var hours    = ("0" + now.getHours()).slice(-2);
var minutes  = ("0" + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
var day      = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month    = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var fileName = hours + minutes + "_" + day + month + ".csv";
var file     = new File("~/Documentos/" + fileName);
file.open("w");
file.writeln("Código,Página");

// get all the matches whitin active document
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "(?i)Cód:\\s*\\d{8}"; // GREP = /Cód:\s*\d{8}/g
var matches = app.activeDocument.findGrep();

// loop trough the matches
var codigo, pageName;
for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
    codigo = matches[i].contents.slice(-8);    // last 8 letters
    pageName = matches[i].parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name; // page number
    // file.writeln(codigo + "," + pageName);  // <-- the proper way
    file.writeln(codigo + "," + (i+1));        // <-- for the simply numeration 1,2,3...
}

file.close();
file.execute(); // open the CSV file


Thank you very much for your response. I believe that the solution you suggested I had already tried before, but the result remains the same. From page 10 onwards (for example, pages 10, 11, 12, 13...), all are grouped on page 1 of the resulting CSV document.

Well. It's weird. Probably there is something unusual with the document preferences. Glad if you solved it somehow. Good luck.

Do you have any idea what document setting might be causing this problem?

Not sure. I wound check the Section and Numbering option in Pages panel first. Some funny glitches with numbers (and tabluation) can be in the Mid-Eastern (Hebrew, Arabic) localized versions of InDesign. If you provide the indd file (or better idml file) I can try to find out.

Thank you all for the help and collaboration. In the end, I managed to solve the problem in the following way:
I created a pageMap mapping. Then, instead of using page.name or documentOffset, the script directly accesses pageMap[i] to get the corresponding page number.
I want to repeat that I have no programming knowledge; everything was solved using artificial intelligence since this code is for personal use. If I had needed it, I would have contacted a professional.
Best regards, and once again, thank you very much.
